# What is the best way to abstract the API calls in Django?

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

When I'm calling API from the client. It is visible in the network tab of google chrome. What is the best way to hide that if I'm writing my APIs in django?

Comment: What your trying to achieve?

Comment: When I'm calling any API from client. The request and response of that API is clearly visible in the networks tab of google chrome. Is there any way that would help me hide the response and request data from the networks tab?

Comment: You can't hide that. Its will be always visible

Comment: Not exactly hide, but, abstract the response, so that no raw data is visible to user.

Comment: You could encrypt the responses? This might help. https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-encrypted-lookup/

Comment: @Riyaaz-0 .. Thanks. This makes some sense.